# Leaving a dropped down ComboBox swallows focus in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have the following problem: on a WPF window I placed a combo box and a button. I drop down the combo box and while the combo box is still dropped down I click on the button. The button does not react on the mouse click but the dropped down combo box closes. After a second mouse click the button reacts.
And here's the code sample:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="100" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Width="100" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="item 1"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="item 3"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Content="Test" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Width="100" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button clicked");
}
```

How can I prevent the combo box to swallow the focus on the button? Thanks.

regards mc

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is intended. It is implemented by creating a panel (`Canvas`) with its `Background` property set to `Transparent` that overlays the entire `RootVisual` before displaying the `Popup` that contains the drop-down list's content. That way, the `ComboBox` control can capture mouse clicks in the entire `RootVisual` area and close the drop-down list when a click is detected.

I wouldn't recommend changing this behavior, really. It's implemented in a way that users expect. If you really want to alter the intended behavior, you can add a *routed event handler* to the combo box in the view's code behind (`YourUserControl.xaml.cs`).

```
MyComboBox.AddHandler(
    UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(
        (sender, e) =>
        {
            MyButton.Command.Execute(null);
        }),
    handledEventsToo: true
);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate a bit why that is the case? I'm using the snippet above in our MVVM application (although the handler is added to a `ListBox`).

Comment: In an M-V-VM approach it is recommended to avoid using event handling in code behind. What you suggest is the opposite. What I need is a general solution for a combobox to resolve my problem, not a "personalized" one. In the exposed case I have a single button, but what happens if a would have a couple of dynamic generated buttons?

Comment: In this case, we're not accessing anything from the view model in the view. In the view's code behind, we're only accessing a component of the view (`MyButton`) and executing its `ICommand`. So, although there's some code-behind, this approach is still legal MVVM. Besides, I have found no other way to resolve this. I would be happy to learn new approaches.

Comment: I'm trying to attach a Behavior<UIElement> object to the ComboBox but until now I have no result. This approach is also M-V-VM compliant.